# Mobile version of the site

Tags: support

Is there a plan for a mobile version for the site?
On my phone (Blackberry 8520) the site works very slow.
I think that a faster mobile version would ve very useful for those of us who are using mobile internet. For example, it took me about 20minutes to ask this question on a mobile. Moreover, I noticed I cannot vote from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 6):

There is [already](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/mobile-stack-exchange/) a mobile version of the site!

Comment: Yes, but Androids Blackberrys and others seem not to work well, according to the comments.

Comment: Sure, but now Beni knows to vote those answers up and maybe write another answer to voice additional concerns.

Comment: Okay, fair enough :)

Comment: I noticed that the site looks different on the phone, which means that there is a mobile version. The idea is that it is not very fast, and if the Androids and Blackberrys do not work well, there is a problem, since these are the most popular phones now besides Iphone.

Comment: @Beni: hmm. According to the comments there are also apps available for various devices at http://stackapps.com/ .

Comment: **Warning** Palm LifeDrive users: surfing to either the main or meta home page crashes the LifeDrive. This did not happen a few months ago.